# What would be an example for something electric which isn't digital?

Tags: terminology

What would be an example for something electric which isn't digital?

By "electric" I mean to any consumer product manufactured and sold as an "electric product" anyone here could buy retail to home/car/business but if there is no such example perhaps an example from science (for example, math, physics, chemistry) might exist.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* There are [almost 200 sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) to choose from, and I think you have asked this in the wrong site. Are you counting simple appliances like those that boil water but have a small microcontroller inside "digital"? In that case a really cheap water boiling pot or the cheapest of rice cookers have mechanisms that control time and/or temperature that will not be considered digital, unless you define a binary "on/off" state as digital :-)

Comment: @uhoh I do indeed define on/off as digital.

Comment: In that case you are asking about something electric that can't be turned on and off?Has there ever been something like that in history anywhere? One can plug it in and unplug it to turn it on and off as well.

Comment: @uhoh indeed what I have proposed is absurd but maybe there is a physical phenomenon which "does with electricity but isn't digital".

Comment: There are materials manufactured to produce permanent electric fields, the simplest are [electrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret#Manufacture) and there are [batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery) and [supercapacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) (but that's not [electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity) which is the *flow* of electric charge) and there are even [various piezoelectric devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity#Application) that can make (very) small amounts of electricity in an analog fashion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about (digital, not digital) devices, not signals. As such, it's off-topic!

Comment: @MarcusMüller why do you say it's about devices when I also wrote about physical phenomena?...

Comment: @freesoftwareistheway because your definition of "digital" does not apply to signals. A signal is digital *exactly if* it's **both** discrete in time and in value. "on or off" is not sufficient. "only has a value for discrete points in time" would also be necessary. Your on/off state is defined for continuous time. None of the things you seem to consider are actually digital signals!

Answer (score 1):

Incandescent bulbs or fuses are consumer products I would  associate to electricity, also they don't produce electricity. Bulbs convert electricity in something else (light) without a flow controller.

From nature phenomena, lightning is an electrical discharge in the atmosphere. Unless we live in a simulation, it is probably not digital. The phenomenon known as static electricity in the human body  may count as well. Nerve cells generate electricity to convey information.

Answer (score 0):

looking around me, I see

1. An analog loudspeaker (passive)
2. Headphone
3. Toaster
4. Ceiling light
5. LED Chain that decorates the front porch
6. My wife's paper shredder
7. Our grain mill for making flour